# pick the last record in a list of variables/ columns

Tags: stata

I have a dataset in `wide` format in Stata and I would like to pick the last observation of each variable. In the example below, I would like to `generate` a new variable based on the last observation of the list of variables.
I tried the code below and it doesn't work. My thought was to pick one variable at a time, e.g. v1==1

```
id  v1  v2  v3  new varible
1   1   2       2
2   1   2   3   3
3   1           1
4   1   4       4

gen new_variable=.
foreach v of varlist  v*{ 
   replace  new_variable=1 if `v'==1
    replace  new_variable=2 if `v'==2
    replace  new_variable=3 if `v'==3
}
```

Comment: You seem confused about some basics. In Stata an observation is a case, row or record in the data. `_N` indexes the last observation in the data. But your problem does not seem to be about the last observation at all. You seem to want to loop over variables, not observations, and pick the last non-missing value in each observation.

Comment: @NickCox, that is what I would like to achieve

Comment: You improved the question but your code still needs editing before it will run. Please do learn about `dataex` in Stata.

Comment: Your code certainly won't catch any value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You want the last non-missing value in each observation (row, record, case) over a series of variables (columns, fields). Terminology in your question is confused.

I first interpret the blanks in your data example as numeric missing values. That being so, what you want is given by the `egen` function `rowlast()`. It can also be obtained by looping as follows

1. Initialise with the first variable.
2. Looping over the other variables, replace if each variable is not missing.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(v1 v2 v3) float wanted
1 2 . 2
1 2 3 3
1 . . 1
1 4 . 4
end

egen WANTED = rowlast(v1 v2 v3)

gen wAnTeD = v1

forval j = 2/3 {
    replace wAnTeD = v`j' if !missing(v`j') 
}

list

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | v1   v2   v3   wanted   WANTED   wAnTeD |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. |  1    2    .        2        2        2 |
  2. |  1    2    3        3        3        3 |
  3. |  1    .    .        1        1        1 |
  4. |  1    4    .        4        4        4 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

I next interpret the data as string variables. The `egen` solution doesn't work but the loop idea does work. Note that missing means empty strings `""`: spaces must be removed or ignored.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str1(v1 v2 v3 wanted)
"1" "2" ""  "2"
"1" "2" "3" "3"
"1" ""  ""  "1"
"1" "4" "" "" 
end

gen WANTED = v1 

forval j = 2/3 {
    replace WANTED = v`j' if !missing(v`j')
}
```